# Map for Custom / Dynamic Route in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I'm trying to figure out how to create a MapRoute for a URL that contains variable segments in the URL.  For example:

https://myapp.net/myapp/resource/{id}/subRescource/{id}

So... the "id" of the resource and the "id" of the subresource should end up as parameters on the call, be it a GET, a POST, a PUT or a DELETE.

I can't figure out how to setup the map route for this, and I haven't been able to find any examples that address this kind of URL (with id's at different levels in the path).

Is there a "simple" answer - just an illustration of what the map should look like?  Or are there examples online for this that anyone is aware of?

Thanks,

- da

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

**MapRoute :**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SubResource",
    url: "myapp/resource/{id}/subResource/{subResourceId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "SubResource", action = "GetSubResource", id = UrlParameter.Optional, subResourceId = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

**SubResource Controller :**

```
public class SubResourceController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public SubResourceModel GetSubResource(long id, long subResourceId)
    {
        // Do something
        return result;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public SubResourceModel AddSubResource(long id, [FromBody]subResourceModel)
    {
        // Do something
        return result;
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public SubResourceModel UpdateSubResource(long id, long subResourceId)
    {
        // Do something
        return result;
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public bool DeleteSubResource(long id, long subResourceId)
    {
        // Do something
        return result; 
    }
}
```

More information about ASP.NET Routing :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: This looks promising - giving it a try...  thanks...!